# Order of n! modulo P

Tags: number-theory

If p is a prime and n is an integer, then $ord_p n!=[n/p]+[n/p^2]+...$. If $ord_p n!=k$ then for every $t <k$,$p^t$ does not divide $n!$ and consequently does not divide $n$. Thus for $t<k$ we have that $n=p^tk_t+r_t$ where $r_t<p$, and thus $[n/p^t]=k_t$. On the other hand $ord_p n!=ord_p n+ord_p(n-1)+...+ord_p 2+ord_p 1$. So we have to separate the case $p=2$ and $p$ an odd number. But I can not go further.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to find the order of n! modulo a prime p. In Ireland's book, it is an exercise which states the above equality where $[r]$ denotes the integer part of r.

Comment: Do you have the inequality $t\lt k$ backward?  After all, $p^k\mid n!$ more or less by definition of $k$, so if $t\lt k$, then $p^t\mid n!$ as well.

Comment: What do you call the *order* mod p?

Comment: Sorry. it is not the order modulo a prime. It s the order at a prime, which is defined as follow. An integer n has order k at a prime p if $p^k$ divides n, but $p^{k+1}$ does not.

Comment: @user103325, my comment regarding the inequality $t\lt k$ still stands.  Do you mean $t\gt k$?

Answer (score 1):

You have $\text{ord}_p(n!) = \sum_{j=1}^n \text{ord}_p(j)$.  Think of it this way.  Each $j$ that is not a multiple of $p$ contributes nothing to this sum.  Each $j$ that is a multiple of $p$ first contributes $1$ to the sum, then (if it is a multiple of $p^2$) contributes another $1$, then (if it is a multiple of $p^3$ ...  The total of the first contributions is $\lfloor n/p \rfloor$.  The total of the second contributions is $\lfloor n/p^2 \rfloor$.  Etc.